# Customize entity in Entity Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can i extend the entity class in EF 3.5 for example below. As i know, it work on EF 4 and above, but not in EF 3.5.

```
partial class car
{
    public car(string carName)
    {
        this.name = carName;
        /* does not contain a definition for 'name' and no 
         * extension method 'name' accepting a first argument
         * of type 'xxx.car' could be found (are you missing 
         * a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to use EF3.5? Also I don't understand your question, you try to give a field that doesn't exist a value in a constructor, why would you expect not to get an error?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck **partial** class

Comment: This technically has nothing to do with EF, but i get what you mean.

Comment: Yes I saw it's a partial class, but if it gives that error, it means you don't have a field named `name`

Comment: The reason i use EF3.5 it's because the IIS .net framework is 3.5. And the team don't wish to upgrade the .net framework. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure both classes are public.
2. Make sure the Property has a public setter.
3. **Make sure they are in the same namespace.**